# How to get the value of three sliders and multiply them in JavaFX?

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, slider

I'm programming a window in JavaFX with three sliders labelled as height, length and width. Every sliders can have a value up to 100. My problem is that I want to add a label volume. This should multiply the values of the three sliders and print it in real time on the window, so if I change the value of one slider, volume should be updated immediately.
I use the package VBox of javafx.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

import java.awt.*;

public class HelloFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Volumen");
        Slider slider1=new Slider(0,100,0);
        Slider slider2=new Slider(0,100,0);
        Slider slider3=new Slider(0,100,0);

        Label label1=new Label("height");
        Label label2=new Label("length");
        Label label3=new Label("width");

        Label infoLabel=new Label("-");
        infoLabel.setTextFill(Color.RED);
        Label infoLabel2=new Label("-");
        infoLabel2.setTextFill(Color.BLUE);
        Label infoLabel3=new Label("-");
        infoLabel3.setTextFill(Color.GREEN);

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 960, 600);
        slider1.setShowTickMarks(true);
        slider1.setShowTickLabels(true);
        slider1.setMajorTickUnit(25.0);
        slider1.setShowTickMarks(true);

        slider2.setShowTickMarks(true);
        slider2.setShowTickLabels(true);
        slider2.setMajorTickUnit(25.0);
        slider2.setShowTickMarks(true);

        slider3.setShowTickMarks(true);
        slider3.setShowTickLabels(true);
        slider3.setMajorTickUnit(25.0);
        slider3.setShowTickMarks(true);

        slider1.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, //
                                Number oldValue, Number newValue) {

                infoLabel.setText("height: " + newValue);
            }
        });
        slider2.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, //
                                Number oldValue, Number newValue) {

                infoLabel2.setText("length: " + newValue);
            }
        });
        slider3.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, //
                                Number oldValue, Number newValue) {

                infoLabel3.setText("width: " + newValue);
            }
        });

        vBox.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        vBox.setSpacing(10);
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(label1,slider1, infoLabel);
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(label2,slider2, infoLabel2);
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(label3,slider3, infoLabel3);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Although a good question, it is always a good idea to add some code, to show the community your efforts.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice :) I added my full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could obviously simply update a volume label in each of your three existing listeners, but a cleaner approach would be to use bindings:

```
    DoubleProperty volume = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    volume.bind(
        slider1.valueProperty()
        .multiply(slider2.valueProperty())
        .multiply(slider3.valueProperty())
    );
    Label volumeLabel = new Label();
    volumeLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("Volume: %.1f", volume));
```

(You can similarly reduce your existing code using simple bindings for each of the existing labels.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I got two exceptions, a RuntimeException and an UnknownFormatConversionException without any informations about where they were thrown.
I inserted your code under the last listener of slider3

Comment: @bfg You just have the wrong format string (`"Volume: %.1f"` in my code). I tested the code I posted directly in your example and it ran just fine.

Comment: How can I change it? I'm sorry, but I'm new to JavaFX so everything is a little bit strange to me :)

Comment: @bfg I don't understand what you're asking. The code I posted runs without errors. If you changed the string format from the example I posted, then you changed it to something that isn't a valid string format. (It's not JavaFX-specific, it's exactly the same as a String format in any other java code.)

Comment: Embarrassing...I forgot 1 in 'Volume: %.1f' You're right, it works perfectly. Thank you very much ;)